# Trim value before reading

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a csv i need to read that in a column it contains an integer value, but there is a space after the value, so the in the csv the value is `"1,264 "`.

In the class i have

```
public int MyValue { get; set; }
```

but when i try to ReadRecords i get the following error:

> TypeConverterException: The conversion cannot be performed.
> Text: '1,264 '
> MemberType: System.Int32
> TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.Int32Converter' IReader state:    ColumnCount: 0    CurrentIndex: 26    HeaderRecord:

Apparently i need to trim the empty space in the field. I have no control over the format of the initial format.

I could make it a string property and parse it at a second pass, but i want to see if there is another way.

**UPDATE**

I tried removing the space and still get the error. I had thought this might have been a culture info issue, and when i am reading i have the following code:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(new CultureInfo("en-US")) {
    TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim  
})) {...}
```

**UPDATE 2**

[image: The code]

Consider a file containing a header with a single column and a single row (besides the header):

```
MyValue 
"1,264 "
```

**UPDATE 3**

My current locale dictates that the comma is a decimal separator and the point is the thousands separator.

Comment: You sure it's not because the text is using a comma for a decimal mark, but you're parsing it in a locale that expects a dot for a decimal mark?

Comment: If you manually remove the space do you still get the error or not? Are you sure the problem is not that comma instead?

Comment: You are both right, removing the comma manually did not fix the error. I am adding some more info in the question.

Comment: Could you try with _TrimOptions = TrimOptions.InsideQuotes_?

Comment: Getting closer, TrimOptions.InsideQuotes trimed the value, but it still cannot parse it. I am adding some sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug into the source code and found the solution.

If you check the source for [Int32Converter](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/Int32Converter.cs) you may see, it converts using the NumberStyles defined in the member as an attribute or get the default of integer.

When I set the NumberStyles attribute to Number then it worked without any other change. I prefer this solution since I do not have to change the expected type of the property.

So I just had to change the class definition to:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Name("MyValue"), CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Optional, NumberStyles(NumberStyles.Number)]
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is correct. You could also specify that the CultureInfo is set to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: I think that this is a lot better than the current accepted answer or my own answer.

Comment: I cannot accept my own answer for 2 days :)

Answer (score 2):

So, as already mentioned in the comments `1.264` is a `double` and trying to parse it as an integer will throw an exception. And the additional space is not a problem in a default CSV configuration:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csvContent = @"Id,Value
1,""1.236 """;

        List<Entry> entries;

        using (var reader = new StringReader(csvContent))
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us")))
        {
            entries = csvReader.GetRecords<Entry>().ToList();
        }

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Id} {entry.Value}");
        }
    }
}

public class Entry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The number i have is with a comma for thousands separator.

Comment: I tried your code directly, an it IS working BUT when i set Value to be of int type, then i get the same error when i use either `,` or `.`.

Comment: Well, i am accepting your answer, cause it does show how to deal with my issue. I do have a question of it is correct to care about a number having a thousands separator in order to determine if it is able to be converted to int or not, but that is a different question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem without changing the int declaration to a double using the [TypeConverter](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion)

Here the steps:

First create the type converter class

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
public class IntegerWithGroupSeparatorConverter: CsvHelper.TypeConversion.ITypeConverter
{
    public string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData mpd)
    {
        return value?.ToString();
    }
    public object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if(Int32.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out int result))
            return result;
        else
            return 0; // Not sure if 0 is acceptable or not
    }
}
public class TestMap : ClassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Value).TypeConverter<IntegerWithGroupSeparatorConverter>();
    }
}
```

Now we can supply this type converter to your reading code with this

```
List<TestClass> entries;
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-us");
using (var reader = new StringReader(csvContent))
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, ci))
{
    csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();
    entries = csvReader.GetRecords<TestClass>().ToList();
}
```